# How to calculate complexity of this program? Can there be any other solution with less complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

Question link: https://leetcode.com/contest/biweekly-contest-1/problems/campus-bikes-ii/

I want to calculate the complexity of this program, I think the complexity of my code is O(b^w) where b is the size of total bikes and w is the size of total workers, though I'm not sure.

In my "bikeAssign()" function which basically works as dfs, At first 1st worker has b (total bikes) options to choose, 2nd has b-1 options to choose, so I think time complexity would be like this-

(b)*(b-1)*(b-2)*......*(b-w) which is nearly equals to O(b^w).

Space complexity: O(w) for dfs (bikeAssign()) only

```
public:
    int assignBikes(vector<vector<int>>& workers, vector<vector<int>>& bikes) {
        int w = workers.size();
        int b = bikes.size();
        vector<vector<int> > dist;

        //complexity O(w*b)
        for( vector<int> worker : workers ) {
            vector<int> v;
            for( vector<int> bike : bikes ) {
                v.push_back( abs(worker[0]-bike[0]) + abs(worker[1]-bike[1]) );
            }
            dist.push_back(v);
        }

        vector<int> vis(b,0);
        //complexity O(b^w) My calculation
        return bikeAssign(dist, vis, 0, w );
    }


    // COMPLEXITY OF THIS FUNCTION ????

    int bikeAssign( vector<vector<int> > &dist, vector<int> &vis, int cnt, int w ) {
        if( cnt == w )
            return 0;

        int res = INT_MAX;
        for( int i=0;i<dist[0].size();i++ ) {
            if( vis[i] == 0 ) {
                vis[i] = 1;
                res = min( res, dist[cnt][i] + bikeAssign( dist, vis, cnt+1, w) );
                vis[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
};
```

This solution is accepted, but I'm getting confused in complexity. Can someone help me to figure out-
1. The complexity of this program with an explanation.
2. Let me know if there is any other solution with a better complexity.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this algorithm recursively scans all possible [variation without repetition](https://www.sangakoo.com/en/unit/variations-without-repetition) of bikes collected by workers, complexity is proportional to this number of variations.

So it is `o(b!/(b-w)!)` where `b = bikes.size()` and `w = workers.size()`. So this algorithm doesn't scale very well.

This looks like a problem similar to [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) (but you have multiple "salesmans").

Comment: Can we apply memoization in this algorithm, If yes How?

Answer (score 1):

> COMPLEXITY OF THIS FUNCTION ????

Let's analysis this complexity -

```
for( int i=0;i<dist[0].size();i++ ) {
      if( vis[i] == 0 ) {
            vis[i] = 1;
            res = min( res, dist[cnt][i] + bikeAssign( dist, vis, cnt+1, w) );
            vis[i] = 0;
      }
}
```

Here this for loop runs `O(dist[0].size())` times. Lets `dSize = dist[0].size();`

So here complexity is `O(dSize)`. But it runs for every dSize (As from the parameter that for loop runs once for each element). So here overall complexity is `O(dSize*dSize)`.

And what is `dSize`? Okay, dSize is the size of *dist[0]*. So that is how much elements are pushed to the `0-index` of `dist` vector. That is numbers of bike. So overall complexity of this function is `O(b*b)`.

Comment: In that case, complexity is O(n^2), but for 1st worker, there are b options and for each option, there are b-1 option for 2nd worker that's what I understand, Need more explanation to digest this complexity.

Comment: so overall b + (b-1) + (b-2) + ... (b-1)
 = (b*(b-1))/2
= (bˆ2 - b)/2
= O(bˆ2)

Comment: As Marek told in his answer I think the same, complexity is b * (b-1) * (b-2) * ... * (b-w).